# how to predict a sentence from a different dimension?

Tags: python

I trained a MultinoialNB classifier to mark senteces as "containing violence" or not (HARM\SAFE), on an existing dataset of sentences (with their lables).

then, i've tried (in the same function, just for the exampe) to predict a new sentence, and it gives me:
ValueError: dimension mismatch

any ideas on how do I solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, 
TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

def train(Text, labels, MODEL_TYPE):   
   bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word", max_features=10000, stop_words='english').fit(Text)
   comments_bow = bow_transformer.transform(Text)    
   tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(norm='l2').fit(comments_bow)
   comments_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(comments_bow)
   features = comments_tfidf

   dict = {'SAFE': 0, 'HARM': 1}
   labels = np.array([dict[b] for b in labels])

   X = features
   Y = labels
   X, Y = shuffle(X, Y, random_state=42)
   kf = KFold(n_splits=NO_OF_FOLDS)
   for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
       Y = np.asarray(Y)
       model = get_model(model_type)
       X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
       y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
       model.fit(X_train,y_train)
   predictions = model.predict(["send nudes"])

if __name__ == '__main__' :

   trainText, Labels = load_data() // a func I build to load data
   train(trainText , Labels , NB)
```

I expect the predicted lable (1\0) but get:
ValueError: dimension mismatch

Comment: Please edit the correction into the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.